# Getting a runtime error everytime i submit my code to google codejam 2020

Tags: python

I`m somewhat new to programming and this is my first time participating for google code jam.

The code written in python 3 works fine when I run tests using sample data but every time I submit the code I get a runtime error (RE).

When I test it with an IDE it runs fine without any errors

My code is:

```
cases = int(input())
final = [];

for p in range(cases):
    N = int(input())
    sample = []
    count =0
    startTimes = []
    c_endTime = -1
    j_endTime = -1
    output = []

    for j in range(N):
        newLine = input()
        sample.append(list(map(int, newLine.rsplit())))


    for k in sample:
        startTimes.append(k[0])
        output.append(0)

    print(output)

    sortedStartTimes = sorted(startTimes)


    for t in sortedStartTimes:
        index = startTimes.index(t)
        endOfT = sample[index][1]
        #print("start: ",t," end: ",endOfT)
        if j_endTime == -1:
            j_endTime = endOfT
            output[index]= "J"
            #print("J End :", j_endTime)
        elif j_endTime<=t:
            j_endTime=endOfT
            output[index]="J"
            #print("J End :", j_endTime)
        elif c_endTime<=t:
            c_endTime = endOfT
            #print("C End :", c_endTime)
            output[index]="C"
        else:
            output.clear()
            output.append("IMPOSSIBLE")
    #print(output)
    stt = "".join(output)
    stuff = "Case #{}: {}".format(p + 1, stt)
    final.append(stuff)

for k in final:
    print(k)
```

I would appreciate any help.

edit: [this](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd27/000000000020bdf9) is the question I`m referring to

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It just says RE(Runtime error) on the page.There is no additional information given

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC I'm sorry for the code not being minimal , but I cant find anything wrong with the code.It is able to get the desired output with the provided sample input data in the question.Also additional information about the runtime error is not provided by google according to codejam rules

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to solve your code exactly because this is not how i solved the problem. But I can provide you with a sample case where your code fails. e-mail?

The RE is a result of your code throwing an error instead of answering the problem in the GCJ. If you solve that and provide results, you will not get Runtime error.

```
1
4
350 436
67 168
250 293
67 149
```

Try running this

Comment: This is NOT an answer to the question.

Comment: He mentioned that any help is appreciated. And i have also edited my answer. I am new to stack overflow. getting used to what to do and what not to do just now. sorry if i did something wrong. :/

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you sort the array? like that it would be away easier to solve since you just compare the last element in both lists C, J with the element you are looping through.